# Populate a jQuery search input by URL

Tags: javascript, jquery, mobile

quick question here.

I'm looking for a way to populate my JQuery search box, with the value entered in the URL.

So I have a URL that looks something like this :

http://****/pub/3/site/ti/store/mobile/page/productList.page

now if I enter something like this at the end

http://*****/pub/3/site/ti/store/mobile/page/productList.page?=brand

I`d like this to appear in my search box. How could I accomplish that ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access [`location.search`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/window.location#Properties), which does include the `?` though.

```
$('input').val(location.search.substring(1)); // set input value to the
                                              // ?... data, omitting the ?
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Y9kdU/